# Standardizing numpy array in Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, standardized

After I trained my model in Keras, it is time for prediction, so I am using some data in order to check my model on. However, the trained model is standardized before training (Very different range of values).

So in order to predict on some data, I should standardize it too:

```
packet = numpy.array([[3232235781, 3232235779, 6, 128, 2, 1, 0, 524288, 56783, 502, 0, 0x00000010, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0]])
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(packet)
rescaled_packet = scaler.transform(packet)
print(rescaled_packet)
```

the output is always 0's: `[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]`

Does any one knows how to standardize numpy array?

Note that a warning error is appearing saying that `DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by StandardScaler. warnings.warn(msg, _DataConversionWarning)` But I do not think that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually comes from the fact that you have only one example in your dataset. When you call `fit` on a table with one example - a mean of each column is computed - but in case when you have only one number in each column - this `mean` is equal to first (and only) row. That's why you are obtaining a vector of `0`'s.

Comment: But in case I can not enlarge my example, because this will be an online capturing of data where only one example will be tested at a time, how this will be solved?

Comment: You could get a part of data - precompute means then - and then `fit` a standard scaller.

Comment: solved it by using the same transformer that I fitted with the training data :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10,1,-4,35,26])
a_stand = (a - a.mean()*np.ones(len(a)))/(a.std())
```

It is what you want ?

Comment: The output of the above example must be something like this: `[[ 0.53640178  0.          0.         ..., -0.88003806 -0.05902683 -0.13751838]`
In your example the output is `[[ 2.82842711  2.8284271  -0.35358918 -0.35358906 -0.35358918 -0.35358918
  -0.35358918 -0.35307304 -0.35353328 -0.35358869 -0.35358918 -0.35358917
  -0.35358918 -0.35358918 -0.35358912 -0.35358918 -0.35358918 -0.35358918]]`